# Blender API: how to distribute an add-on with assets and how to append them with python?

Tags: python, add-on, compositing-nodes, asset

First of all, I'm not a programmer. This is my first time writing code so understand if this question is dumb. So basically this addon I'm making creates a custom node group in the compositor for some effects but I need to open an image with the 'Image Node'. I'm able to do it with Absolute Paths specific to my computer but I don't know how to then distribute my add-on. Is there a way to open images with relative paths once the addon is installed in Blender?

English is not my native language so tell me if I'm not clear :) and thanks in advance

Comment: You can distribute images with your addon, you just need to store them in the zip file and you can access them from the root folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than rely on relative paths, Blender has a mechanism for constructing paths relative to add-on installations.  Here's one way to use it.

When you create your add-on, give it a subdirectory (folder) with a name like `assets`.  Put the image in that subdirectory.

When you create the `zip` file that contains the add-on, make sure to include subdirectories. (The way to do this depends on the OS you're using, but it's usually done by default.)

Then, when the Blender installer (in *Preferences* → *Add-ons*) installs your add-on, it will put the subdirectory in the add-on directory with the image file in the subdirectory.

You can read [*Blender's Directory Layout*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/blender_directory_layout.html) in the manual for details on the directory layout, but what you need to know is that this code:

```py
import bpy
from bpy.utils import resource_path
from pathlib import Path

USER = Path(resource_path('USER'))
ADDON = "my addon name"
IMAGE = "my image name"
srcPath = USER / "scripts/addons" / ADDON / "assets" / IMAGE
srcFile = str(srcPath)
```

will set `srcFile` to a string containing the name of the image in a format acceptable to the local OS.  In my example, on Windows, if your user name is `me`, and you've installed your addon for Blender 2.93, it will produce

```
'C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Roaming\\Blender Foundation\\Blender\\2.93\\scripts\\addons\\my addon name\\assets\\my image name
```

Replace "my addon name" with the name you gave your addon and "my image name" with the name of the image file, *including* any extension (such as `.jpg`) and you can use the string as the image source name.

Pathlib is a standard part of Python.  You can read the python manual section for [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) if you want more details.  Basically, it creates paths independent of the OS conventions and allows you to use the slash ("/") operator to put pieces of path names together in an OS independent way.

Comment: Thank you so much!! This is exactly what I was looking for. you are a life saver :)

Comment: You're very welcome.  I look forward to seeing your add-on when it is finished.